# Receive multiple notifications from server side

Tags: angular, server-side, localnotification

I am working on ionic 4 and angular . My app is content on flights schedule . And everything is working fine . But what i am trying to do is to receive local notification if the flight is arrive . In My code below , i want to make multiple notification for more then one flights . but when i run app i  receive  multiple notification for same flight . How can i do multiple notification for more then one flights ?

Code :

```
 async ActiveNotif() {

    this.ng.run(() => {

      setInterval(() => {

        this.http.get('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&flight=' + this.id + '', {}, {})
          .then(data => {

            let FlightDetails = JSON.parse(data.data);
            this.identification = FlightDetails.identification.callsign;
            this.Fstatus = FlightDetails.status.generic.status.text;
            console.log(this.Fstatus)

          });


      }, 5000)

      if (this.Fstatus == "landed") {

        this.localNotifications.schedule(
          [
            {
              id:0,
              title: 'Your flight has arrived',
              text: 'Your flight ' + this.identification + ' is arrived',
              trigger: { count: 1 },
              sound: "file://assets/one.mp3"
            },
            {
              id:1,
              title: 'Your flight has arrived',
              text: 'Your flight ' + this.identification + ' is arrived',
              trigger:{count:1}

            }

          ]);
      }
    })

  }
```

Comment: hard to say without seeing the back-end.  But just looking at this code, the `this.id` pops out at me.  Are you only passing the id of one flight?

Comment: @BlairHolmes . yes , l am only just passing the id of flights to url . even he tracking the status of flight .

Comment: @BlairHolmes . Like my case it is possible to  pushing notifications via onesignal or firebase message cloud ?